# when I try to do a migration on a hosting I get an error, what should I do?

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to upload a website to hosting. But when in the bash console I write  `python  manage.py migrate`, I get an error.

> File "/var/www/u0932024/data/djangoenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'id'")

what should I do?

Comment: post your views.py

Comment: Is it running locally without problems? It looks like you try to apply a default value for id that does not match the datatype. Check your migrations since your last deploy to see where it might come from. I would also recommend to get a sql dump and replicate the error locally to debug the problem.